# How to combine two rows of a same table by which the same column in the next appears a new column with different name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

EXISRING TABLE

```
name regno subject_code grade result
abc  1000  cs105        C     pass
abc  1000  it100        D     pass
abc  1000  cs117        B     pass
xyz  1001  cs105        E     pass
xyz  1001  it100        A     pass
xyz  1001  cs117        U     fail
```

PROPOSED TABLE

```
name regno subect_code1 grade subjectcode2 grade subjectcode3 grade result
abc  1000  cs105        C     it100        D     cs117        B     pass
xyz  1001  cs105        E     it100        A     cs117        U     fail
```

Comment: You forgot to add the query you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use AS to select the column and name it what you want in the results. From looking at what you have though, you would probably need to include the pass/fail for each class group as well right? Same concept would still apply

```
SELECT table1.name, table1.regno, table1.subject_code AS subject_code1, table.grade AS grade1, table1.result AS result1...
```

Then join in your other data with different aliases.